# pandas multiindex ewma rolling for each sample type

Tags: python, pandas

suppose I want to measure the length of an organ, lets say stomach of several species, ordered by type, 
I create a multi index dataframe from a .csv with repeating values , and I take a sample everyday, making my measures noisy.

How do I apply a rolling  ewma on 60 last samples, for each of the species included in the multiindexed dataframe  ?

dataframe example :

```
arrays = [['mamal', 'mamal','mamal', 'mamal', 'mamal', 'mamal', 'mamal','mamal', 'mamal', 'mamal','bird', 'bird','bird', 'bird', 'reptile', 'reptile'],
          ['whale','whale','whale','whale', 'dolphin', 'dolphin', 'dolphin', 'dolphin', 'cat', 'cat', 'canary', 'canary', 'eagle', 'eagle', 'boa', 'turtle'],
          ['2017-03-01','2017-03-02','2017-03-03','2017-03-04','2017-03-01','2017-03-02','2017-03-03','2017-03-04','2017-03-03','2017-03-04','2017-03-01','2017-03-02','2017-03-03','2017-03-01','2017-03-02','2017-03-03','2017-03-01','2017-03-02','2017-03-03']]

tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(13), index=index)
print(s) :

type     species  measure_date
mamal    whale    2017-03-01      0.913916
                  2017-03-02      0.860045
                  2017-03-03      1.166217
                  2017-03-04     -0.439948
         dolphin  2017-03-01      0.590208
                  2017-03-02      0.297475
                  2017-03-03      0.067966
                  2017-03-04     -0.477495
         cat      2017-03-03     -1.261023
                  2017-03-04     -0.931671
bird     canary   2017-03-01     -1.367815
                  2017-03-02     -0.820792
         eagle    2017-03-03     -0.532935
                  2017-03-01     -0.152090
reptile  boa      2017-03-02     -2.070819
         turtle   2017-03-03      1.329004
dtype: float64
```

suppose I now have longer measure history , keeping a day by day measure, what is the syntaxc to perform a rolling ewma for each species, keeping each of it separate( i don't want to roll over all the measures, but only on the one of the dolphin or the whale )

I have tried

```
b = s.groupby(level=2,group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: pd.ewma(x,ignore_na=True,min_periods=2,adjust=True,com=0.030927835051546))
```

but it only rolls over all the species, not doing a distinction on it ...

```
type     species  measure_date
mamal    whale    2017-03-01           NaN
                  2017-03-02           NaN
                  2017-03-03           NaN
                  2017-03-04           NaN
         dolphin  2017-03-01      0.599637
                  2017-03-02      0.313861
                  2017-03-03      0.099954
                  2017-03-04     -0.476401
         cat      2017-03-03     -1.220229
                  2017-03-04     -0.918025
bird     canary   2017-03-01     -1.308843
                  2017-03-02     -0.786782
         eagle    2017-03-03     -0.553554
                  2017-03-01     -0.186791
reptile  boa      2017-03-02     -2.032299
         turtle   2017-03-03      1.272527
```

Comment: Multilevel indexes start with 0 on the outside and count inwards, so I think you want level=1 for species.  measure_date is level 2, species level 1 and type is level 0 in this example.

Comment: thanks a lot @scottBoston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to correct the `level` as @ScottBoston pointed out:

```
s.groupby(level="second").apply(lambda x: pd.ewma(x,ignore_na=True,min_periods=2,adjust=True,com=0.030927835051546))

first    second   third     
mamal    whale    2017-03-01         NaN
                  2017-03-02    0.661551
                  2017-03-03   -0.726871
                  2017-03-04   -1.873301
         dolphin  2017-03-01         NaN
                  2017-03-02    0.242347
                  2017-03-03    0.276082
                  2017-03-04    0.071822
         cat      2017-03-03         NaN
                  2017-03-04    0.441826
bird     canary   2017-03-01         NaN
                  2017-03-02    1.426628
         eagle    2017-03-03         NaN
                  2017-03-01    0.382538
reptile  boa      2017-03-02         NaN
         turtle   2017-03-03         NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: hi , thanks a lot for your answer ! 
I meant ewma, it is enclosed in pd. ; this is a exponentially weighted moving average, trying to remove the noisy measures, 
I have several parts non working , or things i do no get , maybe due to my pandas version :
- while doing result , i have the following error : 

    AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'rolling'

Comment: @BillyBobJocko2223 I finally got it ;-)